# Change array of string into array of int

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular, I am trying to convert array of string to array of int. But I have no idea how to do it with Typescript.

**My Array**

```
[{x:14,y:"00:12"},
{x:20,y:"13:14"},
{x:40,y:"15:28"}]
```

**What I Need**

```
[{x:14,y:00:12},
{x:20,y:13:14},
{x:40,y:15:28}]
```

Please help me out!

Comment: You should check JS basic types, because what you're asking is not possible,  `00:12` will never, and can't be an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to convert
`[{x: "5", y: "6"}, {x: "4", y: "5"}, {x: "3", y: "4"}]`
**to**
`[{x: 5, y: 6}, {x: 4, y: 5}, {x: 3, y: 4}]`

```
const a = [{x: "5", y: "6"}, {x: "4", y: "5"}, {x: "3", y: "4"}];
const b = a.map(item => {
  return {x: parseInt(item.x, 10), y: parseInt(item.y, 10)};
});
```

Comment: How is this the anwser? This doesn't work with the given input/output O.o

Comment: I like convert a string to number using "+", a.forEach(item=>{item.x=+item.x;item.y=+item.y})

Comment: @Andreas question isn't correct, you can never have y:00:12 key in your object/dictionary. I just tried to answer what correct question might've been :)

Comment: @Eliseo definitely another correct approach, it's just that I work towards immutability of objects wherever required :)

Comment: @FelixChristo Can you please explain how this solves your problem? With your given input this won't work at all...